# Chart.js (v4.2) - weird rendering bug/artifact

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js, render

Very weird and unexpected behavior of Chart.js chart rendering.
Dataset is sorted. Contains 172 timestamps and some Y data.
In Chrome (109.0.5414.75) only happens after messing around with size of the window. In Firefox (109.0) shows up at chart draw animation. Artifact disappears after animation finish.

Best to check out movie for full understanding of what is problem:
https://www.screencast.com/t/a2lXNpn9QP

How it should look:
[image: How normally it should look]

How it looks after messing with window size:
[image: After messing with window size]

Any possible tips on what's going on here and what should I check are very welcome.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/